# Data Validation with MVVM-Light WPF and Linq to Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, mvvm, linq-to-entities, mvvm-light

I think I have read every article google returns when I search wpf mvvm-light data validation and I dont know which way to go.  I am aware of josh smith, Karl Shifflett's, and MVVM LIGHT's own demo techniques for data validation.  What I see is that most validation requires me to fully "re-abstract" my model in my view model.  Meaning that I have to create a property in my viewmodel for each property of my model that I want to validate (and in some cases convert all these into string values for binding/validation).  This seems like a lot or redundancy when all I want to do is mark most fields as required.

I am using LINQ to entity framework(with self tracking) for my model classes which come from a SQL server DB.  As a result I would prefer to keep my business data validation/rules within my viewmodels.  I write a simple service interface to get the data from the model and pass it to my viewmodel.

Most of the examples I can find are from as far back as 2008 (ie josh smith).  Are these techniques still valid or are there more up to date best practices for mvvm data validation with .NET 4.5 etc.

So I am asking:

1) What methods do you suggest I use
2) What methods work best in a LINQ to EF with MVVM-Light Environment.
3) EDIT: I want to provide feedback to user as they enter data, not just when they submit form

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up using the following. I changed my model to use LINQ to self tracking entities (see this article for info about STE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff407090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

LINQ to STE creates an OnPropertyChanged event that implements the iNotifyPropertyChanged interface.

I just created a public partial class for the matching model object (linq entity generated code) I wanted and added an event handler for the `OnPropertyChanged` event. I then used the `IDataErrorInfo` interface to validate and throw errors as I needed. This allows me to validate the fields as they change which gets reflected to the user. This also allows you to perform more advanced validation logic that may need to requery the database (i.e. to look for if a username is already used etc.) or throw a dialog box

Also, having the data validation in the model allows me to still have validation if i perform direct "batch" operations that bypass the UI.

I then used an `HasErrors` and `HasChanges` property and used them to create a Boolean value that gets attached to the relay commands, disabling the crud command buttons if errors are present.

I will post some simple code to outline what I just described, comment if you want more detail.

Here is the Entity Framework extension of the model class:

```
 Imports System.ComponentModel


Partial Public Class client

    Implements IDataErrorInfo

#Region "Properties / Declarations"

    'Collection / error description
    Private m_validationErrors As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Private _HasChanges As Boolean = False

    ''Marks object as dirty, requires saving
    Public Property HasChanges() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _HasChanges
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If Not Equals(_HasChanges, value) Then
                _HasChanges = value
                OnPropertyChanged("HasChanges")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    'Extends the class with a property that determines
    'if the instance has validation errors
    Public ReadOnly Property HasErrors() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_validationErrors.Count > 0
        End Get
    End Property

#End Region

#Region "Base Error Objects"
    'Returns an error message
    'In this case it is a general message, which is
    'returned if the list contains elements of errors
    Public ReadOnly Property [Error] As String Implements System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Error
        Get
            If m_validationErrors.Count > 0 Then
                Return "Client data is invalid"
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal columnName As String) As String Implements System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Item
        Get
            If m_validationErrors.ContainsKey(columnName) Then
                Return m_validationErrors(columnName).ToString
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

#End Region

#Region "Base Error Methods"

    'Adds an error to the collection, if not already present
    'with the same key
    Private Sub AddError(ByVal columnName As String, ByVal msg As String)
        If Not m_validationErrors.ContainsKey(columnName) Then
            m_validationErrors.Add(columnName, msg)
        End If
    End Sub

    'Removes an error from the collection, if present
    Private Sub RemoveError(ByVal columnName As String)
        If m_validationErrors.ContainsKey(columnName) Then
            m_validationErrors.Remove(columnName)
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region

    Public Sub New()

        Me.HasChanges = False
    End Sub

#Region "Data Validation Methods"

    ''handles event and calls function that does the actual validation so that it can be called explicitly for batch processes
    Private Sub ValidateProperty(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.PropertyChanged
        If e.PropertyName = "HasChanges" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        IsPropertyValid(e.PropertyName)
        HasChanges = True
    End Sub

    Public Function IsPropertyValid(sProperty As String) As Boolean
        Select Case sProperty
            ''add validation by column name here
            Case "chrLast"
                If Me.chrLast.Length < 4 Then
                    Me.AddError("chrLast", "The last name is too short")
                    Return True
                Else
                    Me.RemoveError("chrLast")
                    Return False
                End If
            Case Else
                Return False

        End Select

    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

then in the view model I included the following code to bind thecommand and evaluate whether or not it can be executed.

```
 Public ReadOnly Property SaveCommand() As RelayCommand
        Get
            If _SaveCommand Is Nothing Then
                _SaveCommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf SaveExecute, AddressOf CanSaveExecute)
            End If
            Return _SaveCommand
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Function CanSaveExecute() As Boolean
        Try
            If Selection.HasErrors = False And Selection.HasChanges = True Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function

    Private Sub SaveExecute()
        ''this is my LINQ to Self Tracking Entities DataContext
        FTC_Context.SaveChanges()
    End Sub
```

the following is how I bound my button (has custom styling in WPF)

```
 <Button Content="" Height="40" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonAdd}" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Width="40" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Save Changes" Margin="0,0,10,10"/>
```

so, when there are no validation errors and the current client record "isDirty" the save button automatically becomes enabled, and disabled if any of those two conditions fail.  This way I now have a simple way of validating any type of column/data I want for the entity, and I can provide user feedback as they enter data in the form, and only enable CRUD command buttons once all my "conditions" have been met.

This was quite a battle to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this (not necessarily correct) is to do my validation in the ViewModel (where the CRUD operations typically take place), then if there are validation errors, abort saving/adding any data and use `Messenger.Default.Send` to send a custom message type to my view. Then I alert the user via a DialogBox or otherwise.

I've experimented with Binding ValidationRules in the past but found by far the most reliable and consistent method to be simple `if` statements.

Comment: so I assume that you are not providing feedback to the user as they enter data in your form, but validate when the crud command objects are called.

Comment: That's right. If you want to provide live feedback I guess you'd need a binding validation rule, but I've never had much success with these.